# What is the best way to explain how to choose between "its" and "it's"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, orthography, confusables, homophones

Probably one of the most frequent grammar mistakes in the English language is:

> The dog sat on it's mat.

Since spelling checkers don't catch it, and it is even logical, since you would correctly write:

> The dog sat on Fluffy's mat.

What is the best way to explain to a learner of English how to choose between *it's* and *its*?

Comment: You are writing something that is wrong stating it is wrong in the comments, but still... would it be possible to write it crossed out?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is actually really easy, do you mean "it is" or not?

Frankly native speakers seem to make more mistakes with it than foreign learners.

Comment: +1. Foreign learners simply map it to totally different words in their own native tongue. A German would map "it's" and "its" to "es ist" and "sein", respectively, a Russian to "есть" and "его", a French to "c'est" and "son", etc. In other words, foreign learners learn the difference right from the onset and in their own language, where it is immediately apparent. As a foreign learner myself, I never confuse "it's" with "its", because they are two completely different concepts to me that reside in two completely unrelated areas of my brain. The words are homophones, but the concepts are not.

Comment: Right. As someone who learned English primarily from reading, I find these mistakes strange: it's as if people were (erroneously) transcribing spoken sound, rather than writing the words themselves. I have to slow down reading when I come across mistakes of this sort ([especially](http://abstrusegoose.com/151) "your" and "there"…), and switch to saying the words "aloud" in my mind (called "subvocalization"?) and use the listening-interpretation parts of my brain instead of the reading-interpretation parts. :-)

Comment: Just to note that as a native English speaker who is excruciatingly aware of when it is proper to use *it’s* and *its*, I do still occasionally mistype or forget an apostrophe with these homophones. Because they have an identical shape phonologically, they become fused in the internal lexicon. All of this is just further evidence that spoken language truly is primary—at least in native speakers. I think it is especially confusing because the concept of possession is usually (with non-pronouns) expressed with an apostrophe.

Comment: +1 Foreign language learners usually get this right. Native speakers learn to speak before they learn the rules and they learn as kids where they associate the sounds with an idea before they attach the metadata of a word "letter picture" to the concept. Similarly, Japanese kids internalize their characters in a completely different way (by rote) as foreign learner do. Children learn by rote well, Adults learn using reason and accumulated knowledge... thus A native Japanese teacher won't have as much success teaching someone their language unless they change the technique.

Comment: @nohat *"I think it is especially confusing because the concept of possession is usually (with non-pronouns) expressed with an apostrophe"* Why is it different with non-pronouns? Is that worth a question?

Comment: I think I have seen similar mistakes, e.g. "their" written as "there" or "they're".

Comment: Perversely, I used to delight in _It's hair needs cutting_. Until I found that someone had changed Cousin It's name to Cousin Itt.

Comment: Without the other answers, it looks like this one is saying that the word "its" simply doesn't follow the same pattern as words like "Bob's", and therefore is a weird outlier word that doesn't follow any pattern. In fact, it does follow a pattern; the pattern of "his", "hers", etc. It should probably mention that to be a more complete answer.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to remember is that you don't say "he's" or "she's" if you're talking about something someone owns. There are special words for that: "his" and "hers". It follows, then, that there'd be a special word for the genderless "it" too - "its".

Comment: Right. *All* possessive pronouns have their one words without apostrophes: “his”, “her”, “its”, “their”, “my”, “our”, “your”, “whose” (but “one's”). The corresponding words *with* apostrophes all mean something else: “he's”, “she's”, “it's”, “they're”, “I'm”, “We're”, "You're”, “Who's”. Many people seem to make mistakes even when writing “they're”, “you're” or “whose”!

Comment: This answer and the one by jbelacqua are the only answers to say what pattern it is following, and pointing out that it's not just a weird outlier word that magically doesn't follow the "Bob's object" pattern.

Answer (score 20):

Print this out, perhaps.

http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling is good too ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If nothing else works, it can be beneficial to point out that none of these related possessive forms has an apostrophe:

his
hers
**its**
theirs
yours
ours

If something belongs to *it*, *its* form looks just like *his* and *hers* .

If it is short for *it is*, then it's *it's* .

Comment: You have listed the possessive [*PRONOUNS*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc) not the adjectives. In "The dog sat on **its** mat, "its" is a possessive determiner (possessive adjective) not a possessive pronoun. For example, *Whose mat is this?* **It's mine / yours / his / hers** [*It's the dog's*] **its / ours / theirs**. Which would give you *It's its*. A very ugly construction, but grammatical nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Contractions always take an apostrophe. (You can't write *cant* for *cannot*.)

Possesives can, but need not. ("Is that *her* book?" "No, it's *Pat's* book")

Comment: Shouldn't that be "No, it's Pat's book"? Contractions always take an apostrophe, right? It is Pat's book.

Comment: It took a year+ for me to notice the comment as I've not been by. But, I hang my head in shame!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to explain to a learner of English how to choose
>   between **it's** and **its**?

• I sat on **my** mat

• you sat on **your** mat

• he [my brother] sat on **his** mat

• she [my sister] sat on **her** mat

• It [the dog] sat on **its** mat.

• we [my dog and I] sat on **our** mats

• you [you and your dog] sat on **your** mats

• they [he and his dogs] sat on **their** mats.

Note the total absence of any possessive apostrophe. We do not say * *I sat on my's mat*. The [possessive determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner), *its*, is precisely what its grammatical term suggests—possessive; hence the genitive or [possessive apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Possessive_apostrophe) is unnecessary.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Lynne Truss in her book *Eats, Shoots & Leaves: The Zero Tolerance Approach to Punctuation* explains it in a rather straightforward manner:

> The rule is: the word 'it's' (with apostrophe) stands for 'it is' or 'it has'. If the word does not stand for 'it is' or 'it has' then what you require is 'its'.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be understood that there was much disagreement about this up until maybe 60 years ago, when the "authorities" finally agreed that the possessive of "it" should be "its", to avoid confusion with the contraction "it's", meaning "it is" or "it has".

Like any such change in the "rules" of English, it's taken decades to take hold.  And, I'll have to admit, when keyboarding its fairly easy to get it wrong.