# When should I use "your", and when "you're"?

Tags: possessives, contractions, homophones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Your” vs. “you're”: Why the confusion?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/your-vs-youre-why-the-confusion)

Instead of saying "you're free to [...]," I've seen many people use "your free to [...]."

I've seen *your* being used where *you're* should be used. This is especially prevalent in American ads (Craigslist, for example).

Which of the above is correct usage?
I might be wrong; English is not my native language (I'm Asian).

Comment: There is no shortage of this error in the UK either :)

Comment: As an English teacher, I find myself more and more frequently telling my students to ignore what they see around them and trust in themselves that they are right. Isn't that sad?

Answer (score 5):

*You're* is a contraction of *you are* whereas *your* solely refers to possession.  So

> Your free to...

is entirely incorrect.

Comment: It bugs the crap out of me too.

Answer (score 3):

You're is a contraction of "you are."

Your is a possessive form. You're likely to see these words confused with each other because they sound the same in speech.

You're welcome,

Michael

Comment: I am only talking about it's usage in writing, not while talking. I've seen it's wrong usage hundreds of times.  so many times that I started doubting myself, thinking may be I was wrong.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to choose which one to use is to try and substitute with *you are*. If *you are* works then you can use you're, otherwise use your.

For instance, saying

> You're very beautiful today

is the same as

> You are very beautiful today

On the other hand

> These are your shoes

is not the same as

> These are you are shoes

As you can see the last sentence doesn't mean anything.

--

Another thing you can do is to try substituting *I am* or *they are*

> They are very beautiful today

or

> These are they are shoes

Again, the second does not mean anything.

---

And, of course, [10 Words You Need to Stop Misspelling](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling)