# When is it appropriate to use "its" and not "it's" (and vice versa)?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to explain how to choose between “its” and “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its)

Hello,

I am always confused when is the usage of its or it's appropriate. Basically when should I use its and not it's (and vice versa).

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its.

Comment: Was this not question 1 on this site? It should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Its" is a possessive pronoun like "his" or "her", while "it's" is the short form for "it is" or sometimes "it has". Trying to replace it with "her" or "it is/has" helps. I use "her" because for many "his" and "he's" sound to much alike, and "he's" would be a test case for "it's".

Answer (score 0):

*it's* = *it is* or *is has*.

*its* = *belonging (or pertaining) to it*, in the same way that *his* means *belonging to him*.