# "it's" vs "its": what happened lately?

Tags: pronouns

During the course of the last 6-12 months (approx.) online I've seen more and more the mistake of using "it's" in place of "its" and the other way around.

While my habits might have slightly changed, I'm talking about a huge difference here: a few years ago I knew it was supposed to be a "standard mistake", now I notice it almost daily! Even by native speakers!

Assuming it's not "just me", did you notice that? Have any idea of what could be the cause? The only logical thing that comes to my mind is that the Internet is now more cheaper and worldwide, so (no offence intended) we have more non-native speakers and more uneducated people. With "uneducated" I do not only mean they might not *know* proper grammar: I mean they might not *care* to write correctly.

Comment: (I'm sorry if I wasn't clear; it could be quite embarrassing asking such a question while doing some mistakes myself, but, well, I tried -.-)

Comment: Instead of "Even by native speakers!", I would say "Mainly by native speakers." Because they first learned these phrases by listening to other people (and the phrases are pronounced the same way), not by reading a book.

Comment: There are also a great many immigrants to English-speaking countries who don't get the chance to read a lot. Then there is the huge number of speakers of English in countries like India, some of whom probably speak it a lot but weren't educated in grammar so much. At any rate, I haven't noticed any huge difference over the past 10 years. But such a thing is incredibly hard to prove or disprove.

Comment: No offence taken, but do feel free to leave us non-native speakers out of the equation anyway. (^_^) As has been argued [elsewhere](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its/656#656), non-native speakers might actually have *less* trouble differentiating between *it's* and *its*, *than* and *then*, *their* and *there*.

Comment: Oh, true, good points. I'm a non-native speaker too, btw.

Comment: I think what happened in the last 6-12 months is that you went online, or your reading habits changed, or something. :-)

Comment: @Reg: As a non-native speaker, I actually find it very interesting to analyse my own mistakes and to what extent they are typically "foreign". For example, when I typed "their" for "they're" some time in chat, this was considered typically foreign by another participant, though I think it happens to be quite the opposite. Interesting.

Comment: A classic example of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion

Comment: @Cerberus: that might be part of a larger psychological phenomenon. I remember seeing several questions on this very site (though *of course* I can't find *a single one* right now) where there was an answer by a Brit saying "this expression/spelling/pronunciation seems strange to me, I think it's American", and an answer by an American, posted almost simultaneously, saying "this seems wrong to me, I would say it's the British way of doing things". (And both had upvotes.)

Comment: According to http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=its "it's" is the *original* possessive form, and "its" is more recent.  Is language changing again?

Comment: Its a common mistake of the internet and it's users. Jokes apart, I really *hate it*, just like their/they're, that's why I'm mocking.

Comment: Yes, language is changing.  Simple answer.  Blame the internets, texting, foreign non-native English users, and a whole plethora of influences but yes, it's (meaning "it is" here, where the apostrophe is taking the place of the second "i") changing.  Methinks that grammatical rules are really moot since things change all the time, due to people being lazy, ignorant, hurried, incapacitated, under-educated, or some combination of all the above.  Makes me now wonder why I bothered to pay attention in English, Lit, or Latin at all...

Answer (score 18):

I doubt that the average person makes significantly more apostrophe-related errors today than they did five years ago. However, you may be noticing an uptick in such errors due to some combination of the following reasons:

- **The proliferation of informal online content.** I think it's safe to say that today there are more blogs, discussion boards, and other websites created and maintained by non-professional writers than there were 5 years ago. Consequently, a a random page on the Internet today vs. one from 5 years ago is more likely to contain grammatical errors.
- **Confirmation bias.** Once you get the germ of a particular grammatical error in your head, you are sensitive to it, seeing and remembering it more often than you otherwise would.
- **Texting norms.** People text a lot more today than 5 years ago. When texting, adding an apostrophe usually requires a couple button presses, thereby slowing down the user. Consequently, texting often forgoes punctuation marks, including apostrophes. One can assume this behavior would translate onto the web.

Comment: 1: I disagree, because I feel the opposite, and I think the proliferation of *content*, bad quality or good (especially Wikipedia on the good side) has made people, especially childs/teens read more, something that schools make them hate to do. 2: That varies from person to person. I remember an error very clearly when I realise I was wrong all the time, due to shame. 3: I agree, but I take that extra time because honestly it's horrible to see *myself* doing that...

Comment: This probly accounts for a great deal of the impression (though the recency illusion should also be mentioned). One more point, however, is that more and more people have realized that while they don't use or hear apostrophe's in their speech, they're never confused about what's meant, so they don't really need to obsess over such a useless frill. I.e, they've given up with a sigh of relief, and about time, too.

Answer (score 5):

My iPhone offers me "it's" in all circumstances: I have to reject that to get "its". Assuming other iPhones behave likewise (and perhaps other devices too) that would seem likely to account for the proliferation.

Comment: Run for the hills!  Apple has taken over the world! --an iPhone user :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it has gotten significantly worse in just the last few years. The vast majority of people writing today were also writing 5 years ago. That said, it has almost certainly gotten worse over time, as book-reading has declined and grammar has been de-emphasized in primary education.

Apostrophes are notoriously confusing for people, and the default seems to be, "When in doubt, stick it in there." I see things like *CD's and DVD's* all the time, for example.

I think in your case, you have become more sensitive to the error as you have become more aware of it.

Another component may be the proliferation of weblogs and other informal outlets, so although writers have not gotten materially worse, we have been *consuming* an increasingly large volume of informal writing, thus encountering the error with greater frequency.

Comment: "Apostrophes (..) When in doubt stick it in there" - this can be dangerous. See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/comical-examples-of-abused-apostrophes/2491#2491).

Comment: An apostrophe means "look out, here comes an *s* ". Thus "apple's", "monkey's", "dog's", "it's", etc.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: ab'solutely. After all, they dont 'serve any other purpo'se!

Comment: Since nobody has linked to Bob the Angry Flower just yet, I might as well [do it myself](http://www.angryflower.com/bobsqu.gif).

Comment: @Reg: He has stolen my heart already. Reminds me of Donnie from You Suck at Photoshop, really the best way to learn Photoshop and be entertained at the same time.

Comment: Personally I can't understand what's so difficult about using an apostrophe for a contraction and no apostrophe for pluralization.  The simple rule I learned - the apostrophe is replacing a missing letter - is simple and easy to remember, and I can confidently blame my iPhone for any transgressions.

Comment: @Morganpdx: One of the problems is that there are exceptions to this rule, such as the possessive 's versus "it's / its". Another problem are the entirely different rules about the same issue in other languages. The apostrophe is an equally common problem in Dutch.

Comment: @reg @cerb Bob and Donnie are my new best friends.

Comment: @morgan: like many have pointed out, it happens to people more used to talk than they are used to write

Comment: Jay's example "CD's" is what is known as the "greengrocer's apostrophe", since it is traditionally linked to handwritten signs along the lines of "Apple's 50p/lb"

Comment: It's common in my non-english speaking country to see people write English plurals using apostrophes, maybe due to people thinking McDonald's is a franchise of McDonald stores.