# Why is the misspelling of "its" (possessive) so widespread?

Tags: word-usage, orthography, possessives

It happens everywhere: blogs, forums, newspapers, ...

[Example](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-russia-classified-intelligence-information-leak-european-country-stop-sharing-threat-a7738846.html):

> “Regrettably, the time President Trump spent sharing sensitive
>   information with the Russians, was time he did not spend focussing on
>   Russia’s aggressive behaviour, including its interference in American
>   and European elections, **it’s** illegal invasion of Ukraine and
>   annexation of Crimea,” he said.
>   *Independent*

It is so prevalent that even being 100% certain that it should be spelled *its*, I (as a non native speaker) start to think that *it's* is an accepted variant.

1. Am I wrong in thinking that the only correct spelling for the possessive is *its*? Is *it's* an accepted spelling somewhere in the Anglosphere?
2. Are people not aware of this, or they do not care? Very often people make this error repeatedly in a single article.
3. Is it simply a very widespread typo? (really, so widespread??)
4. Should I correct people in forums / comments about this?

Comment: 1. Don't correct users' spellings or use of the apostrophe in forums or in blogs unless your English is impeccable, because you're only inviting abuse from online users. I seen this happening so often, it's become a clichè. 2. Why do people forget to use the apostrophe in `its`? Because it's very easy to forget, and the contracted form `it's` is used much more frequently, so it becomes a habit to add an apostrophe. This is more likely to happen with native speakers then with careful learners (in my experience).

Comment: Actually `including its interference` *is* correct, so it's not every time.

Comment: Some natives must of been lazy ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA the fact that I may make other mistakes does imply that mentioning this one mistake is misplaced, in my eyes. I like to be corrected when I make errors. The thing is, I have the impression that people often do not know about it. But not sure, that's why I ask.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Actually including its interference is correct, so it's not every time". No idea what you did there.

Comment: @oerkelens that kind of makes sense, but `his` `yours` and `theirs` are the counterexamples, and people do not make errors there.

Comment: I was pointing out that "its" was used correctly in that instance, so the author didn't  "misspell" *its* every single time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, yeah, right, I usually do not notice the correctly spelled instances :)

Comment: People are taught that possessives are usually formed by adding 's. So it's natural to fix up "its" and make it look "right".

Comment: @delavnog sorry, but I didn't tell Josh to delete his answer, it was his choice. Maybe he'll see your comment and change his mind. He can undelete his answer whenever he wants. If no one else posts, I'll copy the answer in a community wiki post, I won't gain any reputation, and that way you can have the links etc. Later in the day, don't have the time now,  I might add further stuff to complement Josh's research.

Comment: @MariLouA I think **you're** on to something with **your** overcompensation theory (and should post it as an answer); English requires so much rote memorization of exceptions that the actual rules are overwhelmed. Sadly, I think you're inviting criticism whenever you correct someone's Engish, whether yours is impeccable or not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no issues, constructive criticism is valuable

Comment: @delavnog - Apart from the "constructive" criticism, your question is essentially asking for personal views on a common typo. Why people get it wrong, how to react to it,  and how common this mistake is, probably requires a psychological analysis on one side and a quantitative one on the other. My answer did not and could not address those issues. In other words I misunderstood your question. Sorry

Comment: @Josh maybe my question was not properly phrased. Your answer was interesting, and had valuable information.

Comment: "It's" is the original, correct spelling, and was taught in e.g. American schools as recently as a few decades ago. Given that fact, if anything it should be way more popular. But it's actually not any more widespread than any number of other things like "should of" or "their/there". So what is your reason for singling out this particular word and not any of the thousands of others, where the popular misspelling has actually always been a misspelling? Your collection of rhetorical questions strikes me as pure clickbait and very thinly disguised peeving, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Why was my answer deleted? Perhaps you didn't notice my edit answering the detailed questions?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If the asker didn't know/notice that _usually_ possessives have an apostrophe, is the question (in light of the answer) not _so_ opinion based?

Comment: There are really two questions, why do people do it and why do you find it in writings.  Why do people do it has already been described.  It's an exception and one of many easy mistakes to make, even when you know the correct form.  Why do you find it is because people rely on automated checkers to spot errors.  Some grammar checkers will notice the error, but a spelling checker won't because it's a legitimate spelling.  Even manual proofing can miss it because it isn't something that stands out.

Comment: (See first comment) errata corrige: Why do people **add** the apostrophe in `its`? Because it's very easy to **do**...

Comment: @Mari-LouA While the marked duplicate is useful, I don't see how this question is an exact duplicate of that.

Comment: @NVZ I agree; a better duplicate might be [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8698/191178).

Comment: @NVZ For the sake of openness and clarity, I voted to close this question because it was primarily opinion-based. RegDwight being a mod, can close questions single-handedly. Furthermore, I immediately noted that making this a duplicate of the older question made little sense. I can't remember if I deleted my older comment, or if it has been deleted by the mods.  In any case, I'd appreciate it if you didn't lay the blame squarely on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why" do so many native speakers add an extraneous apostrophe in **its**, is an almost impossible question to answer in a couple of sentences. Below is a selection of excerpts, taken from the Internet, which attempt to shed some light on the matter.

According to the *[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/its-its/)*

> - Most English speakers are comfortable with the difference between its and it’s, yet even the most careful writers mix them up in careless moments. **Such errors are typos, not grammar mistakes** (there is a difference), and can usually be stamped out with a quick proofread. None of us is immune to these mistakes, so let’s not be too hard on people who make the occasional its/it’s slip-up.

*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-it's-vs-its)* explains that **it's**, with *its* apostrophe,  is the older spelling; it replaced the once gender neutral pronoun, **his**.

> - Long ago, English was like many other languages in that every noun had a gender: masculine, feminine, or neuter. Pronouns — those efficient little words we use to stand in for nouns, like *I*, *you*, *he*, *she*, *we*, *they*, and *it* — also had gender; the gender of a pronoun was determined by the gender of the noun it referred to. The possessive pronoun for neuter nouns was *his*: 
>     "April with his sweet showers." **But when English began to link** ***his*** **and** ***her*** **only to actual males and females,** ***his*** **for objects seemed increasingly wrong, and** ***it*** **— with no s — began to be used**: "April with it sweet showers." Around 1600 *it's* began to be used: "April with it's sweet showers." The *it's* had an apostrophe, just like a possessive noun like *April's* would.
> - This apostrophe form of the possessive remained extremely common throughout the 17th century. **The version without the apostrophe only became dominant in the 18th century** — probably because *it's* was taking on a new role, replacing the contraction *'tis*. *It's here* had arrived and *'tis here* was fading away.
> - We still see the possessive *it's* in dashed-off tweets and in flyers from local mattress stores, but the fact that it was right 300 years ago doesn't make it correct today. For those of us who live — and write — in the here and now, use **it's** only when you mean ***it is*** or ***it has***. And drop that apostrophe everywhere else.

[Better@English](http://www.betteratenglish.com/common-english-grammar-mistakes-its-vs-its) offers some invaluable insight as to why so many native speakers make this seemingly elementary mistake, the answer lies in the "sound" they hear in their heads.

> - Some grammar mistakes are surprisingly frequent even among educated native speakers of English. When it comes to written English, a lot of these mistakes involve words or phrases that *sound* the same but are *spelled* differently. Usually these mistakes are obvious when someone points them out to you, but when you are busy focusing on what you’re trying to say rather than worrying about grammatical accuracy, **it’s easy to let the sound you hear in your head trick you into writing the wrong form**. Unfortunately, if you make this kind of mistake, you run the risk of making a really bad impression with your writing. But luckily, some of these mistakes are really easy to fix if you just know what to look for.
> - One of the most notorious of these grammatical pet peeves is when people write the wrong form of **its**/**it’s** [...].

According to the writers over at *[Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/11/its.html)*, the misspelling of *its* is a grammatical error.

> - On a superficial level, this qualifies as both a punctuation error and a spelling error.
> - But on a deeper level, it’s a grammatical error, because it represents a failure to distinguish between (1) the possessive pronoun and (2) the contraction.
> - The language blogger Jan Freeman argues that these “its”/“it’s” errors are merely typos, but comments from readers of our books, articles, and postings over the last 15 years suggest otherwise. **Although a lot of the mistakes are undoubtedly typos, many, many people believe the presence of an apostrophe in “it’s” makes it a possessive.** In fact, Pat’s first book, *Woe Is I*, was inspired by a publisher whose highly educated, adult children didn’t know the difference between these two words.

But for those who repeatedly misspell **its**, despite knowing full well the difference between *it's* and *its*, a [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-29529578) article provides some long awaited solace. It argues that typos and misspellings are in actual fact a sign of intelligence.

> - We should not get overly obsessed with making spelling mistakes or typos, because they are not what makes our writing good or bad, says author and Financial Times columnist Lucy Kellaway.
> - […] an article in *Wired* says we make typos not because we are dim, but because we are clever.
> - Writing is a sophisticated job and our brains focus on the structure, the sentences and the phrases, leaving the close-up work to be done on autopilot.
>     **Afterwards we are programmed to read only what we think we have written, not what we actually have.** If that is the case, it is odd that we make such a phenomenal fuss about them.

Acknowledgements: @Josh

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the post is a community wiki one, which means I don't earn any rep. The first three references were supplied by @josh whose answer is deleted but visible to users with 10K. Why did he delete his answer? Ask him. The OP expressed a vivid  interest in the answer once it was deleted, I have only copied and formatted the excerpts (3) that were in Josh's post. The rest I found and cobbled together.

Comment: Users are kindly invited to improve the answer by  editing or supply further data. The post does not belong to me.

Comment: +1 Good effort. I think it could benefit from a consistent style for use-mention distinction as well.

Comment: Auto-correct might also deserve a mention here. At least I’m fairly confident that the vast majority of times that I end up adding an unwanted apostrophe come about by me typing _its_ and my phone then unilaterally (and sometimes too quickly for me to notice if I’m already typing the next word) changing that to _it’s_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet please add, modify, or rearrange as you see fit. I don't consider this to be "my" answer. I only posted it because the OP expressed interest in Josh's answer, and I felt, in part, responsible for his deletion. He deleted it minutes after I had posted my second comment, so hard not to think it was my "fault". Anyway, go ahead and make this answer truly "community".

Comment: Uh… any suggestion that *Most English speakers are comfortable with the difference between its and it’s* is risible. They're clearly not, as should be evident to anyone with a big mail basket… 

The OQ is a single example yet I suggest the majority of native speakers couldn't begin to answer the question, even if they understood it.

Answer (score 1):

Possessive is usually denoted by apostrophe + s ("possessor's"), and *its* is an exception. Anyone who was never taught (or has forgotten) that it's an exception, will spell it *it's* instead of *its*. Though I haven't asked each and every person who misspells it if that is the case, I have come across this being the case, and I think it's a logical mistake.

As for your specific questions:

> 1. Am I wrong in thinking that the only correct spelling for the possessive is *its*? Is *it's* an accepted spelling somewhere in the Anglosphere?

Proving that there is *no one* who spells a word differently (purposely) is not practical, so I assume this question is mainly part of your main one, you are offering a logical explanation as to why people would spell it differently. But since I think my answer above is logical, and since I haven't found any current dictionary (granted, my search was pretty cursory) saying otherwise, my answer would be: No. You are not wrong.

> 2. Are people not aware of this, or they do not care?

Again, I didn't ask everyone, but those who I've corrected, were unaware. I doubt people who ensure their spelling of other words is correct, would have a case against one word.

> 3. Is it simply a very widespread typo?

I think that the answer to No. 1 answers this too - this is unlikely (as you pointed out), and you are probably asking this only for lack of a better answer.

> 4. Should I correct people in forums / comments about this?

Since this is a general question not specific to "its", and deserving a separate question, I am answering it in line with No. 1 again - *Can* you correct them or might it not be a correction at all? And as there - I think it *is* a correction, though, I don't know if correcting people's spelling mistakes is a good idea.

Side note: as mentioned in another answer here - *it's* actually was a correct spelling in the past.

Comment: Uh… this isn't a general question not specific to *its*.

The full etymology is long and unusual, and spelling possessive *its* without an apostrophe is a deliberate distinction from *it's* as a contraction of either  *it is* or *it has*.

It's nothing like a mistake or error or typo… it's the correct spelling