# Is "Most of it's in English" normal English?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, contractions, apostrophe

The phrase "Most of it's in English" is [grammatically correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its) (it's short for "Most of it is in English"), but it doesn't feel right. Is there a reason it doesn't feel right?

**Edit:** The thing I'm concerned about is "it's" versus "it is".

Comment: This may be a better question to ask in [chat]. How it feels to you may be different than how it feels to others.

Comment: @MrHen: Not sure why the fact that different people may feel differently about a usage means it's not valid for OP to ask about it. Seems just as on-topic to me as, for example, "How offensive is 'cock-up' to Americans"?

Comment: Perhaps the question about ["That's what it's"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its) is relevant (that question is also about "it is" versus "it's"). Or perhaps not.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It's. (Relevant, that is)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: That would be more relevant if we were discussing "**Most of it's**" as a possible reply to "**Is it in English?**". But we're not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right, I agree. It's not relevant. In fact I think "Most of it's in English" is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You and the rest of the English-speaking world (apart from OP), I suspect! :)

Comment: The subject of this phrase is "Most", not "it." There may be a rule against using a weak form of "is" against a word that is not its subject. Someone with a proper grammar text should look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it's right, and it's usual enough. It means, of course, that some communication is in a mix of languages, but that the majority thereof is being communicated in the English language.

Comment: Agreed -- seems like a perfectly normal, boring utterance of English...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the reason it doesn't feel right is because even in the 'contracted' form it has four repetitions of the short "i" sound.

Personally I find the full form (with *five* repetitions) quite difficult to say quickly.