# When is necessary to use "its" and how to use it correctly?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

For example, I was writing the following sentence:

"Sony donates 5% **of profit** to good causes."

How can I know that is necessary to use "its" in that sentence, as follows:

"Sony donates 5% **of its profit** to good causes"

Comment: Or "...of its profit..." even!

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a third alternative. Use *its*. (See [What is the best way to explain how to choose between "its" and "it's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its))

> Sony donates 5% of its profit to good causes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my question in order to save time to anyone that will visit this page.